# Deputy CIO or CIO Deputy

Tags: terminology, it-its-itself

I saw everywhere Deputy CIO (Deputy Chief Information Officer), 
but how do I prove it?
Could you advise me the source (with IT positions) I may use as a reference?
HR department uses CIO Deputy, but I suggest it is wrong.

Comment: See also [workplace.se]

Comment: If he's a deputy how is he "chief"?

Comment: "HR Department" needs some sort of determiner in front of it, probably *the* or  *our*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the Google Books corpus can give a reasonable picture of how words are used in printed works. Querying for *deputy CIO* and *CIO deputy* in a case-insensitive search to yield both titles and job designations, you get this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Deputy%20CIO%2CCIO%20Deputy&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CDeputy%20CIO%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BDeputy%20CIO%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeputy%20CIO%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

This doesn’t mean that *CIO deputy* has never appeared in printed sources, but that a query could not find at least 40 hits.

To narrow down the results, you might try an Elephind search, which queries a number of collections of scanned newspapers. A query for [*CIO Deputy*](https://elephind.com/?a=q&hs=1&r=1&results=1&txq=%22CIO%20deputy%22&txf=txINtxCO&o=10&dafyq=&dafmq=&dafdq=&datyq=&datmq=&datdq=&puqname=Search%20all%20titles...&puq=&lcq=&csq=&e=-------en-10--1--txt-txINtxCO-CIO%20deputy---------) yields 11 hits, all of which are OCR errors for "ex-officio deputy" because the software couldn't handle the ffi ligature.

These results should convince your HR department. When it comes to language usage, an argument from silence should always win.

Comment: I struggle to come up with any titles of the form “Title Deputy” in lieu of “Deputy Title”, starting with how the sheriff’s deputy is the *deputy sheriff*, not the *✻sheriff deputy* and going from there. Even in longer forms like *assistant deputy attorney general*, we’re still talking about an assistant deputy-AG and not something else.

Comment: That in a compound _deputy_ is always attributive would have taken longer to prove. A deputy mayor isn't a mayor deputy either.